# Repeating a drawing between nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

Using the following code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, arrows.meta, backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{tree}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\inct}{1.96}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\inc}{1.2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\incc}{.3}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\yc}{1.88}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\incyc}{1.1}
\tikzset{cano/.pic={
\draw [red, line width=\inc mm] (0,0) node (o){} circle (\incc) (135:\incc) -- (-45:\incc);
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\draw [blue, line width=\inc*.8 mm, -latex] ([shift={(90:\incc*1.6)}]o.center) -- +(-90:\incc*4.4);
\draw [red, line width=\inc*.8 mm, -latex] ([shift={(0:\incc*12)}]o.center) -- +(180:\incc*8);
\end{scope}}}%circle arrow no
\vspace {-.8cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9, transform shape]
\node[black] at (0,0) (begin) {Education};
\node[black] at ([shift={(-90:\inct*1)}]begin.center) (nb) {Investment};
\node[black] at ([shift={(-90:\inct*2)}]begin.center) (nc) {New factory};
\node[black] at ([shift={(-90:\inct*3)}]begin.center) (nd) {Local employment};
\node[black] at ([shift={(-90:\inct*4)}]begin.center) (ne) {More tax revenue};
\node[black] at ([shift={(-90:\inct*5)}]begin.center) (nf) {Better public services};
\begin{scope}[yshift=-11.cm]
\foreach \position in {(0,\yc*\incyc*1), (0,\yc*\incyc*2), (0,\yc*\incyc*3), (0,\yc*\incyc*4), (0,\yc*\incyc*5)} \draw \position pic {cano};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like to do the following:

1. repeating the circle/arrow drawing between the nodes, which does not look symmetric
2. make the text left aligned, not centered

to look like the following figure

[image]

Comment: You can define a new command then.

Comment: @JouleV Would you please tell me how. Thank you

Comment: I will be out for a while, so I can't provide an answer now. In short, you can define a command like `\something (x)--(y);` which draws an arrow like that from node (x) to node (y). At last you only have to draw the leftmost arrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [my previous answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/475778/156344) on your question:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\def\yourcommand (#1); {
    \coordinate (center) at ($(x#1)+(1.7,-1)$);
    \begin{scope}[scale=0.4]
        \draw[line width=.75mm,blue,-latex] ($(center)+(0,1.5)$)--($(center)+(0,-2)$);
        \draw[line width=1.5mm,red] (center) circle (1 cm);
        \draw[line width=1.5mm,red] ($(center)+(135:1)$)--($(center)+(-45:1)$);
    \end{scope}
    \draw[line width=.5mm,red!70!black,latex-] ($(center)+(.75,0)$)--($(center)+(2.5,0)$);
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={font=\sffamily}]
\foreach \i in {0,...,5} {\coordinate (x\i) at (0,-2*\i);}
\node[right=1cm of x0] (edu) {Education};
\node[right=1cm of x1] (inv) {Investment};
\node[right=1cm of x2] (fac) {New Factory};
\node[right=1cm of x3] (emp) {Local Employment};
\node[right=1cm of x4] (tax) {More Tax Revenue};
\node[right=1cm of x5] (pub) {Better Public Services};
\foreach \i in {0,...,4} {
    \yourcommand (\i);
}
\coordinate (centerleft) at ($(x2)+(-1.25,-1)$);
\draw[line width=.75mm,blue,-latex] ($(x5)+(0.75,0)$) to[out=180,in=-90] (centerleft) to[out=90,in=180] ($(x0)+(0.75,0)$);
\begin{scope}[scale=0.4]
    \draw[line width=1.5mm,red] (centerleft) circle (1 cm);
    \draw[line width=1.5mm,red] ($(centerleft)+(135:1)$)--($(centerleft)+(-45:1)$);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Edit 1:

To add text to the red horizontal arrow, we can add more arguments to the command:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\def\yourcommand (#1) node[#2] #3; {
    \coordinate (center) at ($(x#1)+(1.7,-1)$);
    \begin{scope}[scale=0.4]
        \draw[line width=.75mm,blue,-latex] ($(center)+(0,1.5)$)--($(center)+(0,-2)$);
        \draw[line width=1.5mm,red] (center) circle (1 cm);
        \draw[line width=1.5mm,red] ($(center)+(135:1)$)--($(center)+(-45:1)$);
    \end{scope}
    \draw[line width=.5mm,red!70!black,latex-] ($(center)+(.75,0)$)--($(center)+(2.5,0)$) node[#2] {#3};
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={font=\sffamily}]
\foreach \i in {0,...,5} {\coordinate (x\i) at (0,-2*\i);}
\node[right=1cm of x0] (edu) {Education};
\node[right=1cm of x1] (inv) {Investment};
\node[right=1cm of x2] (fac) {New Factory};
\node[right=1cm of x3] (emp) {Local Employment};
\node[right=1cm of x4] (tax) {More Tax Revenue};
\node[right=1cm of x5] (pub) {Better Public Services};
\yourcommand (0) node[right] {Some text};
\yourcommand (1) node[right=1cm] {Dummy text};
\yourcommand (2) node[midway,above] {Hello};
\yourcommand (3) node[below] {Some stuff};
\yourcommand (4) node[above] {Some other stuff};
\coordinate (centerleft) at ($(x2)+(-1.25,-1)$);
\draw[line width=.75mm,blue,-latex] ($(x5)+(0.75,0)$) to[out=180,in=-90] (centerleft) to[out=90,in=180] ($(x0)+(0.75,0)$);
\begin{scope}[scale=0.4]
    \draw[line width=1.5mm,red] (centerleft) circle (1 cm);
    \draw[line width=1.5mm,red] ($(centerleft)+(135:1)$)--($(centerleft)+(-45:1)$);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @JouleVThank you very much. Just one more comment, can some variable text be added to the end of the red horizontal arrows!

Comment: @JouleVas for example \node[xshift=1cm, yshift=-1cm of x0] {Edu poor};

Comment: @Hany See my edited answer.

Comment: @JouleVThank you very much. I appreciate your answer and its modification very much.

Answer (score 1):

an alternative, with using `tikz` library `arrows.meta` (for arrows),  `matrix` (for positioning of nodes) and `calc` (for drawing of symbols). symbols with arrow are defined as node style using `path picture`:

**edit:**
adopted to `beamer` document class. image size is now determined by selection radius of symbol. appropriate values seems to be between `0.15` in `0.35`. scaling with `scale=...` doesn't work.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc, matrix}

\newcommand\ppbb{path picture bounding box}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize\sffamily,
 short/.style = {shorten <=1mm},
  symb/.style = {minimum size=4*\r cm, 
                 path picture={
                 \draw[line width=3*\r mm,blue,-{Triangle[angle=90:1pt 2]},short]
                        (\ppbb.north) -- (\ppbb.south);
                 \draw[line width=4*\r mm,red] (\ppbb.center) circle[radius=\r]
                            ($(\ppbb.center)+(135:\r)$)--($(\ppbb.center)+(315:\r)$);
                                },
                node contents={},
                pin=0:{#1}},
symb/.default = {},
every pin/.style = {pin distance=13mm,
                    pin edge={line width=2*\r mm,{Triangle[angle=90:1pt 2]}-,red}
                          },
                        ]
\def\r{.25} %by size of symbol you can scale image size
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes,
             column 1/.style={anchor=west}]
{
Education                       \\
\node[symb];                    \\
Investment                      \\
\node[symb=some text];          \\
New Factory                     \\
\node[symb];                    \\
Local Employment                \\
\node[symb=another text];       \\
More Tax Revenue                \\
\node[symb=important];          \\
Better Public Services          \\
};
\draw[line width=3*\r mm,blue,rounded corners=8mm,
      -Straight Barb, short]
    (m-11-1.west) -- ++ (-1.2,0) |- coordinate[pos=0.25] (aux) (m-1-1);
\draw[line width=4*\r mm,red] (aux) circle[radius=\r]
                            ($(aux)+(135:\r)$)--($(aux)+(315:\r)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @ZarkoThank you very much for your answer. Just two comments please, how to scale the whole drawing down, say by .8. I tried to do it, but I could not. And how can this drawing be put after \begin{frame}

Comment: @Hany, see edited answer.

Comment: @ZarkoThank you very much for your time to develop this nice code.